# How to append to txt file into the last line created previously

Tags: linux, awk, sed

```
if 
python python_rule1 >> raw-data.txt

python python_rule2 >> raw-data.txt

if the output from rule1 is A

if the output from rule2 is B

then the raw-data.txt

A

B
```

How do I get:

```
A, B
```

Comment: Please do wrap your samples in code tags, Also do add your efforts which you have put in order to solve this problem in your post.

Comment: no problem but i am not quite sure what you mean could give me an example so i know what to do for next time thanks

Comment: Sorry, this is not the way StackOverflow works. Questions of the form "I want to do X, please give me tips and/or sample code" are considered off-topic. Please visit the [help] and read [ask], and especially read [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Comment: echo $((`cat /sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone0/temp|cut -c1-2`)).$((`cat /sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone0/temp|cut -c3-5`)) >> /home/pi/Myideas/energy/raw-templog2.txt

Answer (score 0):

From the question, it looks as if there are two programs "python_rule1" and "python_rule2", producing single character output (A or B).

The desired output is to place the two responses in the same line on stdout, delimited by comma, instead of sending two lines to stdout. This can be achieved by storing the result of each step in to shell variable (R1, R2 in the example), then formatting the output to stdout

```
R1=$(python python_rule1)
R2=$(python python_rule2)
echo "$R1, R2" >> raw-data.txt
```